# encoding error by python when using Apple Silicon

Tags: python, macos, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I am uing Python to work with csv file.

I am using same code, but it is working with windows, i run that with MacOS Monterrey (my macbook using M1 chip) but it was fail like below:

```
File "/Users/ptit9x/Desktop/parser_project/parser.py", line 6, in <module>
    data = file.readline()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 15-16: invalid continuation byte
```

--> After that, I changed encoding mode to ISO-8859-1, old error was disappear but i met new error like below:

```
P!bîh^[Content_Types].xml ¢( ¬ËNÃ0E÷HüCä-JÜ²5íÇ*Q>ÀÄÆªc[iiÿûB¡j7±ÏÜ{2ñÍh²nm¶Æ»R
      ÈÀU^/ÅÇì%¿rZYï 1__fq·ÃR4DáAJ¬h>ãÚÇVßÆ¹
                                                    ªZ¨9ÈÛÁàNVÞ8Ê©ÓãÑÔji){^óã-I"{Üv^¥P!XS)bR¹rúK¾s(¸3Õ`cÞ0½ÝÎß»¾7M4²©ôªZÆk+¿|\|z¿(ôPúº6h_-[@!ÒØPk´­2nÏ}Ä?£LËðÂ Ýû%áÄßºdN"m,à¥ÇDO97*~§ÈÉ¸8ÀOíc|n¦ÑäEøÿöéºóÀBÉÀ!$}íàÈé;{ìÐå[îñé2þÿÿP!µU0#ôL
      _rels/.rels ¢( ¬MOÃ0
                           ïHüÈ÷ÕÝBKwAH»!T~IÜµ£$Ý¿TG½~üÊÛÝ<êÈ!öâ4¬;#¶w­úqu*&rFq¬áÄvÕõÕöGJy(v½*«¸¨¡KÉß#FÓñD±Ï.W  ¥=ZÆMYÞbø®ÕBSí­°·7
```

Below is my code (after change encoding utf8 -> ISO-8859-1):

```
import csv
file=open("message_logger.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1",mode = "r")
data=file.readline()
print(data)
```

And i don't know actually encoding of csv file, i just export that from my system

Comment: Please show us the code that generates this error, not just the error. And some sample, ideally. See [ask].

Comment: import csv
file = open("message_logger.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1",mode = "r")

# Read file, create a list of raw data
data = file.readline()


print(data)

Comment: above is my code, just open file, read and print out data

Comment: Please [edit] that into your question as a code block. All critical information should be in your question. Comments can be deleted at any time for any reason, plus as you can see it is very hard to read code in comments. With a whitespace-sensitive language like Python, it is impossible.

Comment: What is the actual encoding of `message_logger.csv`? It looks like you have made a few guesses, but guessing at encoding is rarely a good idea. Where does it come from?

Comment: @Chris, i already upload my code in question, it is very simple. And i don't know about actual encoding of message_logger.csv. I just export that from my system. P/S: this code already work in windows enviroiment

Comment: "I just export that from my system"—how, exactly? What is "my system" here? The issue may have more to do with how you generate that file than with how you read it.